# How to use login info from one site to log in to another on a different server

Tags: database, authentication

Not completely sure this question has been answered, as our situation is slightly different.

We are making an affiliate website on Joomla platform for a company that already has a membership website. That is you have to log in to get to the information on their site. We would like to use that username and password fields from that site's database to allow the user to log in to the affiliate site. We'd rather not create two separate databases so that the user has to remember two logins.

I'm thinking you write (in some language) something like:

1. ask the user for username and password in a form, and put those into
          variables as strings
2. get the values from the company website and put them into variables
          as strings
3. compare the username variables and the password variables

   if not equal, alert the user, clear the form, and let them start
          over

   else, log the user in

First, can it be done? Second, what programming language should I (well our outsourcer) use? Third do can you encrypt the the information as it is going from the one server to the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but you can in html do something like this:

Step1. Make a input field (Username, Password, blah blah)
Step2. Id of input should match that of second site login
Step3. For every input do

```
action="Enter site name here.com"
```